# Is there a way to store an Array which contains Map inside of it in a MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to store the [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yDwb.png) of this type in my MongoDB database.
I have created a Schema in mongoose as follow:

```
questionData:
    [{
        type: Map,
        of: String
    }]
```

The problem I am facing is that when I save the data the data gets saved as an empty data as follow:

[DB data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbdxk.png)

I have tried a lot by changing schema and other ways but couldn't get it working.

Comment: I fixed this by converting the map that I want to send in the database to JSON while still maintaining the schema the same way.